# How to create List<Custom object>

Tags: c++-cli

I have a project in C++/Cli and native mixed . I created a custom object and i want to create a list of that object type seems not to be ok . Here is the code:

```
  #pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "..\..\Toolkit\Include\TypeHelper_h.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; 
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

namespace TypeHelperControl {

public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){List<TypeVariable^>^ m_someObj;};
    ~MyClass();

private:

};


 public ref class TypeVariable 
 {
 public:

     TypeVariable(String^ VariableName,String^ VariableType,String^ VariableValue)
     {
      this->m_Name = VariableName;
      this->m_Type = VariableType;
      this->m_Value = VariableValue;
     };
     String^ get_Name()
     { 
         return m_Name;
     }
     String^ get_Type()
     {
         return m_Type;
     }
     String^ get_Value()
     {
         return m_Value;
     }
 private:
     String^ m_Name;
     String^ m_Type;
     String^ m_Value;
 };

};
```

List^ m_someObj; Is generating multiple errors

```
error C2059: syntax error : '>' 
error C2065: 'VariableType' : undeclared identifier
error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

Thank you

Comment: It should be `List<TypeVariables^>^` Regarding other errors, please post your code and exact error message.

Comment: I hope you also included TypeVariables.h file, as required in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define "TypeVariable" before your first usage:

```
public ref class TypeVariable 
{

};

public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        List<TypeVariable^>^ m_someObj;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
error C2065: 'VariableType' : undeclared identifier
```

I believe this error is caused because at this point in the file, the compiler hasn't seen the class `TypeVariable` yet. I recommend reorganizing your classes into individual header files, and #including them appropriately, but the quick & dirty solution would be to stick a `public ref class TypeVariable;` forward declaration above the definition of `MyClass`.

```
error C2059: syntax error : '>' 
error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

These errors should go away when the above error is resolved.